# IIS7.5 PHP not logging errors in subdirectories

Tags: php, iis, logging

I'm working with win7, IIS7.5, php 5.2.17 now, and I have a problem with the php error logging: Error logging works well as long as the entry point (called php file) is not in a subdirectory of the document root. (Display error shows the error in that case, but error is not logged.)

Any idea how to solve that?